# Get undefined property error after declare varible in async created Nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js, undefined, server-side-rendering

I'm working with nuxtjs in ssr mode, i'm having this function to setup data for my component. I keep getting
Cannot read property 'data' of undefined. But some how myInfo state still get the data. Can someone explain why this happend. Here is my code

```
async created() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  await this.initData();
},
methods: {
  async initData() {
    let myInfo;                
    if (this.param) {
      if (this.$store.userLogin) {
        myInfo= await this.$repositories.api1(this.param);
      } else {
        myInfo= await this.$repositories.api2(this.param);
      }
    }
    this.myInfo= myInfo.data;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a function to setup data for component in Nuxtjs, using async created

Comment: The code you shared is not sufficiently self-contained. We cannot know what `this.$repositories.api1(...)` returns, for example, if it resolves to an object containing a `.data`. If it did not, that would explain the error. Either share more of the relevant code or, even better, use debugging or `console.log(myInfo)` to find out what these functions return. Perhaps that already answers your question.

Comment: Also, use `asyncData` or `fetch` lifecycle hooks if using Nuxt, rather than `created`.